# Low oil pressure but no light?

Tags: oil-pressure, citroen-c3

I drive a Citroen c3 2017.

My car recently came up with a message on the screen saying low oil pressure, however the light hasn’t come on? I did however stall at the time but could someone advise if I should be worried ?

Answer (score 1):

Different lights or messages may occur under separate criteria. If you got the message during a stall, the stall itself could have been the cause for the message. But if it were me personally, if there is ever a question of oil pressure, I would have it checked immediately. If there is one thing that will always, unconditionally and unforgivingly ruin an engine, it is low or no oil pressure.